# ObservableCollection.Insert on index bigger than length of collection

Tags: vb.net, collections, insert

I'm wondering, what happens when you do following:

```
Collection.Insert(55, "Input")
```

The collection contains 20 items, so 19 would be the last index.
This doesn't work, I get the expected outofrangeException.
But when I do :

```
Collection.Insert(20, "Input")
```

That works without a problem, even though it is 1 out of the collection.

Any thoughts on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you want to insert to collection after the last item in the collection. Spec of Collection(Of T).Insert: ArgumentOutOfRangeException if index is greater than Count Property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132411.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If index is equal to Count, item is added to the end of Collection(Of
>   T).

Stated from the  MSDN.

So basically if you insert at index = `count`, its like an `append`, you add after the last item.